# inotifywait name space issue

Tags: linux, bash, inotify

I follow the "/ home" directory and its subdirectories with the bash script below. but when the directory names are blank, the script does not work correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -m -r -e moved_to -e create "/home"  | while read path action file 
do
    echo "$path$file -> $action"
done
```

Simple 1

/home/new_folder1/new_text.txt

script output

```
/home/new_folder1 -> CREATE,ISDIR
/home/new_folder1/new_text.txt -> CREATE
```

Simple 2

/home/new folder1/new text.txt

script output

```
/home/new folder1 -> CREATE,ISDIR
/home/newCREATE new text.txt -> folder1/
```

sorry bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a custom format that puts both path components in the rightmost field:

```
inotifywait  --format="%e %w%f" | while read -r action fullpath
```

Comment: Yes, it worked that way smoothly. thank you so much

Comment: Note: if the sole purpose of `while read` was to `echo` in the other format (and not to parse further) then `--format="%w%f -> %e"` will do this, without the loop.